# how to access any html element through jquery when it is stored in js variable?

Tags: jquery

when my html elements are stored in variable then how can i access any html element from the variable.
suppose if i need to extract or manipulate div called "dv1" or dv2. may be i may need to insert row
in table mytab. then how can i do it? please help me with sample code.

```
$("#btnPrint").click(function () {
sHtml = "<div id='dv1'><table id='mytab'>";
                sHtml += "<tr><td>" + "<img src='" + ImgPath + "' border='0'/>" + "</td></tr>";
                sHtml += "<tr><td>" + $('#lblTxt').html() + "</td></tr>";
                sHtml += "</table><div id='dv2'>my content here</div></div>";                
            return false;
        });
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the string to a jQuery object, and then manipulate it.

```
$html = $(sHtml);
$html.find('#dv2').text('Test');

$html.find('#mytab').append('<tr><td>Test</td></tr>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass your html string to jquery to transform it in a jQuery object that you can manipulate as usual.

```
var sHtml = '<div id="mydiv"><p>some html code ...</p></div>';
var $sHtml = $(sHtml);
$sHtml.find('#mydiv').append('<p>something</p>');
```